# RIP v2 Network Command

Tags: cisco, ip, network, subnet, rip

I am comparing the Boson ExSim Lab to the Neil Anderson's Lab on RIP.

On one of the labs on Boson ExSim, it asks to configure RIP on the routers, all of which are on some form of a 192.168..0.0/24 network. When I try to use the network command, I put "network 192.0.0.0", which I thought would work, but when I "show ip rip database", the routes haven't been advertised and nothing shows up.

When I watched Neil Anderson's video, all of his routers are on some form of a 10.0.0.0 network. But when he uses "network 10.0.0.0", everything converges just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most people probably have no idea what labs you are talking about. Please provide details on the labs you are referring to, and please post your configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you include the `no auto-summary` command in the RIPv2 router process, RIPv2 will assume classful networks the way RIPv1 does.

I have not seen either of those labs, but it seems that the Neil Anderson Lab includes the command. Try putting it on the Boson ExSim Lab, and it should start working.

It only works if you have the `version 2` command in the RIP router process because RIPv1 can only do classful advertisement.

Comment: As a side note, using 'network 10.0.0.0' which may assume a /24 network would match the actual 10.0.0.0/24 network just fine. Or if the software in use is particularly old or has very 'generous' (broken) assumptions baked in, it may assume 10.0.0.0/8 and things would work. 

192.0.0.0 (assumed /24) is not at all the same as 192.168.0.0/24 and 192.0.0.0 should never be assumed to be a /8 because only 192.168.0.0/16 is part of the RFC1918 allocation for private networks. The rest are for other purposes and organizations.